# Netbeans 7+ collaborative client/server

Tags: svn, netbeans, tortoisesvn, collaborative

I am trying to configure a collaborative scenery in my work. This is the problem:

We are 3 programmers. We perform many changes (software) everyday day in our personal computers, and then we upload those files to the server. The quality team reviews our work every day, so, the copy on the server is updated for each change (localhost/www/our_program).

Is there some configuration using any SVN + NetBeans to keep updated the files of our local server (www/our_program) and that give us the possibility to work in a local copy and then when we commit the files SVN updates the files on the server?

Thanks. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link: http://brennydoogles.wordpress.com/2011/10/21/using-subversion-to-automatically-publish-your-website/, essentially the **Updating Your Website After SVN Commit** part.

I'm afraid NetBeans is not a good choice to handle SVN hooks. You should use TortoiseSVN to trigger them: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository-hooks.html